# Extra pixels being added to my line-height

Tags: css

Very simple. A `<div>` with one word of text at `16px` with `line-height` of `1`. Somehow, Chrome and Firefox add an extra pixel of space above the text and the bottom of the text bleeds out of the bottom a little. IE adds even more space. Is there no way to make the `line-height` consistent with no added space?

http://jsfiddle.net/XrVmR/1/

Comment: why are you setting line-height to 1? the reason i ask: http://jsfiddle.net/XrVmR/3/

Answer (score 0):

[Set `border: 0 px`](http://jsfiddle.net/XrVmR/1/)